# livecheck doesn't work on a cask "Version '0.2.1' differs from '' retrieved by livecheck."

Tags: homebrew

I create a cask on brew

```
cask "pronote" do
  version "0.2.1"
  sha256 "36366e0353cb4a7be95c78617205440a55985bd7cdbedf6a3e39466ee96f72b7"

  url "https://tele7.index-education.com/telechargement/pn/v2023.0/exe/Install_PRNclient_FR_2023.#{version}_win32.dmg"
  name "pronote"
  desc "Logiciel"
  homepage "https://www.index-education.com/fr/"


  app "Pronote"
end
```

When I do `brew audit --new-cask pronote`. I have this error

```
 Version '0.2.1' differs from '' retrieved by livecheck.
```

I add different strategy of livecheck on the program, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Brew-Livecheck):

> The brew livecheck command finds the newest version of a formula or
> cask’s software by checking upstream. Livecheck has strategies to
> identify versions from various sources, such as Git repositories,
> websites, etc.

You can either implement livecheck for your cask, or simply disable it with:

```
livecheck do
  skip "No version information available"
end
```